# How to create a Raining Effect(Particles) on Android?

Tags: 2d, android, particles

I am developing a 2d android strategy game, it runs on SurfaceView, so I can't(or can I?) use LibGdx's particle system. And I would like to make a raining effect, I am aiming for something like this( http://ridingwiththeriver.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/rain-fall-animation.gif ), I don't need the splash effect in the end (although that would be superb, but probably would take up a lot of system resources). 
How could I achieve that raining effect? Any ideas?

Thank You a lot in advance!

Answer (score 11):

Conserve your precious CPU/GPU cycles! You can inexpensively approximate rain (and rain splats) without using particles. The rain drops and splats don't even have to move or be aligned! Basically, randomly draw a bunch of the following sprites onto the screen:

[image]

Source: [bulletproofoutlaws.com](http://bulletproofoutlaws.com/elusive-ninja-the-shadowy-thief/game1-day-19-makin-it-rain-unfortunately-not-with-dollar-bills/) (There's also a video of the final effect)

Answer (score 5):

I made a rain shader for 3D without using any particles at all ([Video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bo0GRQaSUg4) but instead using three layers of the same texture scrolling by at different speeds at different scales as described in the article [Rendering Falling Rain and Snow](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/graphics/~pisith/references/Rendering%20Falling%20Rain%20and%20Snow.pdf).

For 2D you obviously would not want a double cone to project your rain textures on but can use a plane instead. You can however use the effects with twisting a little (I think, haven't tested it) to create a feeling for velocity left or right. For back or forward you could just scale a little along the y-axis.

Answer (score 2):

since it's a 2D game, I don't think you'll need a complete particle system to create beautiful rain. here is an idea : just create a rain animation and tile that all over the screen.

Comment: What kind of animation do you mean exactly?
Thank You for answering :).

Comment: I can't find something I like right now, but the idea is simple. animation should be only rain drops moving down, also it should be repeatable, and tile-able. every other pixel in each frame is completely transparent

Answer (score 2):

Somehow, very primitive Java example without using shaders.

```
    class ParticleSystem
    {
    int maxParicles=10000;
    float ParticleMaxLifeTimeMS=5000;
    particle[] Particles;
    emitter Emitter;
    billboard BillBoard;
    public void Emitt()
    {//emission code goes here}
    public void Evolve()
    {//explosion code goes here}
    class particle
    {
    float SpawnTime;
    float CurrentLife
    float x,y;
    float Vx,Vy;
    float r,g,b,a;
    float mass;
    float scale;
    }

    class emitter
    {
    float x,y;
    float EmissionRate;
    }

    class billboard
    {
    int materail_handler;
    float height,width;
    }
    }
```